# jquery slide toggle iframe overriding hide or show

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, google-dfp

I've got this code that hides/shows a div depending on whether the user clicks a button to do so. It also sets a cookie to remember the state, so that if the user refreshes the page the div state stays the same. All is working fine, until I add the code to show a DFP ad, and for some reason the iframe it uses is overriding the hidden state when the page is refreshed - it still shows the ad, even though the containing div is hidden?

Here is my code, I would appreciate any help to get this sorted :-)

Thanks

As it is now http://jsfiddle.net/jamesisapayne/xhzes/

```
<style>
#billboardButton {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    color:#666;
    padding:3px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

<!-- Load the latest version of jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Load the jquery.cookie.js plugin -->
<script src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7ZDS1Dob8_8WXhpUVdtNjVNdWc/"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
    '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/4856165/Forum_Billboard_970x250', [970, 250], 'billboard').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().setTargeting('SiteType', 'giraffetest');
    googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check to see if the billboardStatus cookie has been set
    if($.cookie('billboardStatus')) {
        // If yes, define the variable
        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus');
    } else {
        // Else set it as true by default and with an expiry date of 1 day = 24 hours
        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus', 'true', {expires: 1});
    }
    // On refresh, if the cookie value is false i.e. the ad spot is closed
    if(cook=='false') {
        // hide the billboard ad spot       
        $('#billboard').hide();
        // Change the open/close button settings
        $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", "#e1e1e1").text('Open Ad');        
    } else { // Else if the value is set as true i.e. open
    // Show the ad spot
    $('#billboard').show();
        // Change the open/close button settings
        $("#billboardButton").text('Close Ad');
    }
    // When the user clciks on the open/close button…
    $('#billboardButton').on('click', function() {
        // Toggle the opening/closing of the ad spot
        $('#billboard').stop().slideToggle('slow', function(){
            // Set the background colour and the text value of the button depending on what state the button is currently in
            $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", $(this).is(':not(:visible)') ? "#e1e1e1" : "").text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close Ad' : 'Open Ad');
            // Set the cookie value to false i.e. closed
            $.cookie('billboardStatus', $(this).is(':visible'), {expires:1});
        }); // End slideToggle
    }); // End on click
}); // End document ready
</script>
<div style="width:970px;margin:20px auto;">
    <div id="billboardButton">Close Ad</div>
    <div id='billboard' style='width:970px; height:250px; background-color:#0C9;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            //googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('billboard'); });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Managed to find the answer by adding the dfp code in via jQuery rather than straight into the html. Have put the invocation code into two lines (59 and 73) and tested it. Here is the finished code…

```
<style>
#billboardButton {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    color:#666;
    padding:3px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

<!-- Load the latest version of jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Load the jquery.cookie.js plugin -->
<script src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B7ZDS1Dob8_8WXhpUVdtNjVNdWc/"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
    '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/4856165/Forum_Billboard_970x250', [970, 250], 'billboard').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().setTargeting('SiteType', 'giraffetest');
    googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check to see if the billboardStatus cookie has been set
    if($.cookie('billboardStatus')) {
        // If yes, define the variable
        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus');
    } else {
        // Else set it as true by default and with an expiry date of 1 day = 24 hours
        var cook = $.cookie('billboardStatus', 'true', {expires: 1});
    }
    // On refresh, if the cookie value is false i.e. the ad spot is closed
    if(cook=='false') {
        // hide the billboard ad spot       
        $('#billboard').hide();
        //$('iframe,#google_ads_iframe_/4856165/Forum_Billboard_970x250_0').css('display','none');
        // Change the open/close button settings
        $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", "#e1e1e1").text('Open Ad');        
    } else { // Else if the value is set as true i.e. open
    // Show the ad spot
    $('#billboard').show().html("<script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('billboard'); });<\/script>");
        // Change the open/close button settings
        $("#billboardButton").text('Close Ad');
    }


    // When the user clicks on the open/close button…
    $('#billboardButton').on('click', function() {
        // Toggle the opening/closing of the ad spot
        $('#billboard').stop().slideToggle('slow', function(){
            // Set the background colour and the text value of the button depending on what state the button is currently in
            $("#billboardButton").css("backgroundColor", $(this).is(':not(:visible)') ? "#e1e1e1" : "").text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Close Ad' : 'Open Ad');
            // Set the cookie value to false i.e. closed
            $.cookie('billboardStatus', $(this).is(':visible'), {expires:1});   
            $("#billboard").is(':visible') ? $("#billboard").html("<script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('billboard'); });<\/script>") : "";     
        }); // End slideToggle
        return false; 
    }); // End on click
}); // End document ready
</script>
<div style="width:970px;margin:20px auto;">
    <div id="billboardButton">Close Ad</div>
    <div id='billboard' style='width:970px; height:250px; background-color:#0C9;'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use

```
onClick="funtionName()"

funtion funtionName(){ 
  $('#iframeID').toggle(); 
}
```